# How to resolve Autolayout issue in Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift

Here I had used activity indicator programmatically and given constraints programmatically but got crashed at the `NSLayoutConstraint` returning an error can anyone help me how to resolve this ?

here is my error in console

> 2017-11-04 16:46:41.657 Ecommerce[2744:71044] *** Terminating app due
>   to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Unable to
>   activate constraint with anchors  and
>   
>   because they have no common ancestor.  Does the constraint or its
>   anchors reference items in different view hierarchies?  That's
>   illegal.'

```
func showActivityIndicator(uiView: UIView) {
    container.frame = uiView.frame
    container.center = uiView.center
    container.backgroundColor = UIColorFromHex(rgbValue: 0xffffff, alpha: 0.3)

    loadingView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 80, height: 80)
    loadingView.center = uiView.center
    loadingView.backgroundColor = UIColorFromHex(rgbValue: 0x444444, alpha: 0.7)
    loadingView.clipsToBounds = true
    loadingView.layer.cornerRadius = 10

    customActivityIndicator.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40)
    customActivityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.whiteLarge
    customActivityIndicator.center = CGPoint(x: loadingView.frame.size.width / 2, y: loadingView.frame.size.height / 2)

    loadingView.addSubview(customActivityIndicator)
    view.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    container.addSubview(loadingView)
    container.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    NSLayoutConstraint(
        item: container,
        attribute: .centerX,
        relatedBy: .equal,
        toItem: view,
        attribute: .centerX,
        multiplier: 1.0,
        constant: 0.0
        ).isActive = true

    NSLayoutConstraint(
        item: container,
        attribute: .centerY,
        relatedBy: .equal,
        toItem: view,
        attribute: .centerY,
        multiplier: 1.0, 
        constant: 0.0
        ).isActive = true
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: container, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: contentView, attribute: .width, multiplier: 1, constant: view.frame.size.width / 2).isActive = true
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: container, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: contentView, attribute: .height, multiplier: 1, constant: view.frame.size.height / 2).isActive = true
    contentView.addSubview(container)
    customActivityIndicator.startAnimating()
}
```

Comment: One thing that seems wrong to me in your code, is that you create the constraints, but never really assign them to some view.

Comment: @WolfgangSchreurs, the constraints are activated, so iOS adds them to the proper view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your subviews before you create the constraints.

Move this line:

```
contentView.addSubview(container)
```

to before the creation/activation of the constraints.

Comment: now its not crashing but it is out off screen how to display it in centre ?

Comment: You need more constraints.  Once you set `container.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`, the `frame` is not used.  Set a `width` and `height` for your `container` view.

Comment: I had given width and height also but it is lying on side of screen

Comment: Your `container` is centered in your `contentView`.  How is your `contentView` placed on screen?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pchD5.png it is displaying like this shown here in image

Comment: Please describe the various parts.  It is not obvious from the picture what is the `container`, what is the `contentView` and what do you want the screen to look like?

Comment: on container I added loading view in which grey colour u seen in image and on that I added activity indicator and container is added on content view where the content view is placed on scroll view

Comment: If you want the activity indicator to be in the center of the physical screen, try centering it to `uiView` center instead of `container` center.

Comment: how to place it centre ?

Comment: on content view I am trying to add and I had added my complete code

Comment: Add your container as a subview of `uiView` and center it to that view.

Comment: BTW, you invalidated the original Q&A by moving the  `contentView.addSubview(container)` in your question.  You should put it back or my answer makes no sense.